# Git: Untracked files on client side of project

Tags: git

I added a `client/` side to my node with react project and git is complaining about it, saying that the files inside it are untracked. I have never had this problem before when working on similar projects where there is a client side inside the overall server-side project. This is what I get:

```
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
(use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

new file:   client
modified:   routes/authRoutes.js
modified:   services/passport.js

Changes not staged for commit:
(use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
(use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working 
directory)
(commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)

modified:   client (modified content, untracked content)
```

I just want to be able to do work on both the server side and client side and have git track of all of it without giving me the above message. How do I fix this?

It seems it expects me to `cd` into `client/` and add to git there, why can't I just do that in the root directory?

Comment: Because you have a git repo inside a git repo?

Comment: @matt, aha, that was not done on purpose, how to correct it?

Comment: Delete the invisible _.git_ directory that's inside the _client_ directory?

Comment: @matt, that did it. thank you